# Data Conversion to Time Series in R

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, r, forecasting, data-analysis

I have sales data for 2018 and 2019. I would like to convert it to time series. The data does not have daily sales:

```
View(df)

Sales          Date 

75606         11/01/18

95620         16/01/18

55666         21/01/18

56270         29/01/18

45600         11/02/18

65620         18/02/18

50660         26/02/18

76200         10/03/18

75606         20/03/18

95620         27/03/18

55666         28/03/18

56270         29/03/18

45600         17/04/18

65620         24/04/18

50660         02/05/18

76200         16/05/18
```

And so on until 2019 December.

Here the problem is if I convert it to time series by using following code:

```
tsn <- ts(df[,1], start =c(2018, 1), frequency=12)
```

It is considering only $1^{st}$ 12 rows
The output will be having $1^{st}$ 12 values

So how do I convert the whole data into time series? Should I aggregate monthly wise and convert that into time series or is there any way to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of multi-parallel-time-series.

Example shared on github [MultiParallelTimeSeries](https://github.com/vipinbansal1/multipleparalleltimeseries), believe that will be helpful.

Comment: I need in R Language

Answer (score 0):

Check the Date column type if it is a character you need to convert it into the date format and then change the dataframe to time series object using xts function from xts package.

```
library(lubridate) 
df$Date <- dmy(df$Date)
library(xts) #used to convert dataframe to ts object
tsdf<-xts(df,order.by=df$Date)
```

Comment: The data frame has converted to xts and zoo class. The data captured well for all the dates available. But I can't do ets arima models using this. How to proceed further